# getting the image to the previous UI,after selecting the image form gallery

Tags: java, android

I have UI which contains the four thing

1) Date
2) Message
3) Socialnetworking
4) Attachment with image

1)For Date ,when i click on the date ,then DateTimePicker comes and i select the date

2)For Message ,when i click on the message ,then new activity is there to write the 
message and then press the done then message comes back to  the previous UI with message contains

3)For Social Networking,same thing as 2 points is happening

4) But for Image attachment ,when i click the attachment ,it opens the new Activity with UI for selecting the image form the gallery ,The image is selected ,but i want to take the image back to the previous UI .

For Coming new activity and for getting back to the previous UI,i am plying with the Visibilty gone and VISIBLE.

please suggest ,what i can do for fetching the image and get back to the previous screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your first activity from which u will pass intent for gallery:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

        Uri SelectedImage = data.getData();
            String filePath = null;

        try {
            // OI FILE Manager
            String filemanagerstring = SelectedImage.getPath();

            // MEDIA GALLERY
            String selectedImagePath = getPath(SelectedImage);

            if (selectedImagePath != null) {
                filePath = selectedImagePath;
            } else if (filemanagerstring != null) {
                filePath = filemanagerstring;
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unknown path",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e("Bitmap", "Unknown path");
            }

            if (filePath != null) {
                ProfilePic.setImageURI(SelectedImage);
                   //or decode if u want to reduce the size 
            } else {
                bitmap = null;
            }
            FROM_GALLERY = true;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Uploaderror", e.getLocalizedMessage());
          }
       }
  }
```